# Is there a mantra to destroy negative energies before taking food or drink?

Tags: mantras, yoga, ayurveda

Is there a mantra to destroy or neutralise influence of negative energies(ie:germs, microbes, bacteria, krimi, ghosts etc in food/drink) before taking food or drink to mouth? Does chanting gayatri mantra or om Namo narayanya loudly before drinking/eating something, serve this purpose?

Comment: there is a ritual - offering food as as neivedyam to bhagavan in your house , and eating remnants as prasad. there is also parisechana mantra, that is for dwijas (who have undergone upanayana). every food we eat has some himsa associated with it - even if it is vegetarian, some insects would have been killed in the process. so this is a way of prayaschitta.